# I can withdraw my BTC on cryptoayo and they insisting on me to pay an amount ...?? How can one unlock block chain and be independent and withdraw?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

[image]

Hello guys ...Im asking how can I withdraw from cryptoayo and there is a block chain that doesn't wanna release my current balance and it's 23,825 been trading on auto trading for six months

Comment: A scam. Normally withdrawal fees are deducted, not requested. Don't pay them, you won't receive your money back.

Comment: Then please look up if cryptoayo.com is legit or not because my account is active but can't access the funds ....

Comment: They are scam, I couldn't find even one review about them. They seem to be have poorly made their website from a shopping website template you can see how unprofessional they look here: https://cryptoayo.com/product/fresh-organic-honey/ Seek help from your local authorities to get your money back.

Comment: The app is cryptoayo.com and Im amazed when they say organic

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1072/5406